# MediaStream Unhandled Promise Rejection: [object DOMError] (in Safari 11)

Tags: javascript, safari, promise, webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

I am getting an Unhandled Promise Rejection in Safari Tech Preview 11 in my method below to initialize WebRTC. Specifically, it occurs when I assign the `MediaStream` to the video element like this: `video.srcObject = event.stream;` -  the stack trace shows that this line is the one that threw the exception. I have not been able to catch the exception using `try/catch.`

The exception is only occurring in Safari 11 (does not occur in Chrome).

Here is the method:

```
initWebRTC(p){
    var self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      self.state.connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
      self.state.connection.socketMessageEvent = 'webrtc-firebase';
      self.state.connection.setCustomSocketHandler(FirebaseConnection);
      self.state.connection.firebase = 'webrtc-firebase'; 
      self.state.connection.enableFileSharing = true; 
      self.state.connection.session = {
        audio: true,
        video: true,
        data: true
      };
      self.state.connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
        OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
        OfferToReceiveVideo: true
      };
      self.state.connection.onstream = function(event) {
          console.log('event.mediaElement',event.mediaElement);
          console.log('event.stream',event.stream);

          var videoContainer = document.getElementById('videoContainer');
          var video = event.mediaElement;
          if (!window.safari){
            var source = document.createElement("source");
            source.srcObject = event.stream;
            video.appendChild(source);
          } else { // Safari
            try{
              video.srcObject = event.stream; // this is the line that throws the exception
            }catch(e){ //unable to catch the exception
              console.log('exception',e);
            }
          }
          videoContainer.appendChild(video);

          var playPromise = video.play();
          if (playPromise !== undefined) { // not a Promise in some browsers
            playPromise.catch(function(error) {
            });
          }
          setTimeout(function() {
            var playPromise = video.play();
            if (playPromise !== undefined) {
              playPromise.catch(function(error) {
              });
            }
          }, 5000);
      };
      resolve();
    });
  }
```

Not sure if this helps, but here is the trace:

```
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: [object DOMError]
    (anonymous function)
    rejectPromise
    onstream (index.js:5787) // this is the video.srcObject = event.stream; line
    (anonymous function) (RTCMultiConnection.js:4092)
    getRMCMediaElement (RTCMultiConnection.js:1113)
    onGettingLocalMedia (RTCMultiConnection.js:4064)
    onGettingLocalMedia (RTCMultiConnection.js:4984)
    streaming (RTCMultiConnection.js:3289)
    (anonymous function) (RTCMultiConnection.js:3358)
    promiseReactionJob
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Safari 11 blocks  from autoplay any video with sound by default ([source](http://adage.com/article/digital/apple-blocks-autoplay-video-safari-web-browser-update/309266/)).

I believe the `video` element comes with the autoplay attribute. When you set `srcObject` to it, it will try to play the video -- and then got blocked by Safari. That's why you see the error.

You can try to remove `autoplay` from the video element, then you may be able to catch it in `playPromise.catch`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this can work for you but I had a similar issue, the fix was add the 'muted' attribute to the video tag, after that everything is working again, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Rigter. it's working. but still have error :)